# Custom Exception translator not invoked in Hibernate/Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have written code to handle a specific Oracle error code. I extend the LocalSessionFactoryBean to implement additional logic to the session factory creation.

```
class MyLocalSessionFactoryBean extends LocalSessionFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public DataAccessException translateExceptionIfPossible(RuntimeException ex)
    {
        if (ex instanceof HibernateJdbcException)
        {
            // Oracle serialization exception has SQL state [72000]; error code [8177]
            SQLException sqle = ((HibernateJdbcException) ex).getSQLException();
            if (equal(sqle.getSQLState(), "72000") && sqle.getErrorCode() == 8177)
                return new CannotSerializeTransactionException("Cannot serialize transaction access", ex);
        }

        return super.translateExceptionIfPossible(ex);
    }


}
```

It is declared in XML as the primary `SessionFactory` bean and works as it.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801512/spring-how-exception-translation-works), but the difference is that I use SessionFactory rather than EntityManager. I think my setup is fine in order to take advantage of persistence exception translator. Also, my DAOs are annotated `@Repository`

Unfortunately whenever I get a transaction serialization from Oracle, and only from Oracle, I get it propagated through all the stack trace. I could debug and LSFB's `translateExceptionIfPossible` method is never invoked.

```
Exception in thread "processRunManager-dequeue" org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [72000]; error code [8177]; could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:248)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:755)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:590)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91)
                at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
                at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
                at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118)
                at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:153)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy272.pick(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1806.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy273.pick(Unknown Source)
                at com.acme.Dequeuer.run(ProcessEngineImpl.java:298)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
                at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
                at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3184)
                at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3063)
                at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3443)
                at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
                at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
                at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3159)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:491)
                at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
                at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
                at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
                at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
                ... 24 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: impossibile serializzare l'accesso per questa transazione

                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
                at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:384)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
                ... 43 more
```

The exception, as predictable, happens on `@Transactional`'s commit phase. It is correct that the exception is thrown by JDBC to Hibernate, but should be translated by Spring using my code, so that Spring `@Retry` can replay the transaction again.

How do I get my custom exception translator working?

Comment: I affirm that my code is never invoked because my breakpoint didn't fire, not because the exception was not translated as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit.

Such exception is thrown only at commit phase. My DAOs are annotated `@Repository`, but not `@Transactional`, so any operation will pass through DAO's `@Repository` annotation holding the [exception translator interceptor](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.html) without problems. When `PlatformTransactionManager` tries to commit, however, it is not decorated properly with a `PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor` as shown in the stack trace.

HibernateTransactionManager only translates `HibernateException`s and `PersistenceException`s.

As I said in my question, I determined that Hibernate does not translate SQLException with those specific Oracle error codes to the correct subclass of HibernateException.

Solution 1 is to decorate services using DAOs with `@Repository` or solution 2 (our approach) to dispose of serialized transactions in favour of [pessmistic row locks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#lock-java.lang.Object-org.hibernate.LockMode-)